# Do the digits of $\sum_{k=0}^n20^k$ repeat?

Tags: summation, decimal-expansion

Consider the summation $\sum_{k=0}^n20^k$. Do the last digits of this always repeat? For example, with $n=54$ the summation is

$$\sum_{k=0}^{54} 20^k \\= 18\,962\,524\,746\,823\,141\,052\,631\,578\,947\,368\,421\,052\,631\,578\,947\,368\,421\,052\,631\,578\,947\,368\,421$$

Where the last 54 digits are 052 631 578 947 368 421 repeated 3 times. (I also plugged in higher values and got similar results)

Is there a proof of this result?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It's $\dfrac{20^{55}-1}{19}$

Comment: See if you can see a connection to $\dfrac1{19}$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I mean, I know that my example summation with k=54 is equivalent to that (it's just a finite geometric series after all), but I'm not quite sure what that has to do with my question

Comment: @player3236 Hmn, I see that the repeating digits are the same as the repeating decimals of 1/19, which is interesting. it probably has to do with the fact that the infinite series sums to -1/19 (by just applying the infinite geometric series formula).

Comment: $p$-adic numbers strike again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{54}20^k$ is a geometric series, so it's $\dfrac{20^{55}-1}{19}$.

$20^{55}=2^{55}\times10^{55}$, so it concludes with a long string of $0$s,

and $20^{55}-1$ concludes with a long string of $9$s.

Picture dividing $20^{55}-1$ by $19$ using long division.

Once the long string of $9$s starts, there will be a particular remainder,

which is a non-negative integer less than $19$.

Bring down the next $9$ and divide by $19$ to get another remainder.

Since there are only finitely many possible remainders,

eventually we will encounter a remainder that we have encountered before,

and at that point the cycle will repeat, until we run out of $9$s to bring down

and we are done dividing.